# Sorting items which know their previous

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of items. Each item has an ID and a PREVIOUS_ID field. How can I efficiently sort them and detect any cycles (an error condition)?

To complicate it, I need to sort them in a single sequence but mutliple items might have the same PREVIOUS_ID.

Comment: Does this mean you want to sort them by ID, or you want to sort them by reversing the `PREVIOUS_ID` links?

Comment: I want to sort them in the order they define themselves in, by pointing to what they should come after.

Comment: How would you sort A[id:1,prev:none] B[id:2,prev:1] C[id:3,prev:1] ?

Comment: As @Kwariz said, can you have multiple branches?

Comment: A B C or A C B would be equally correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to sort them in a single sequence"? Do you have to scan the list of items only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose one at random, and follow the previous ID path until there is no previous item. At that point, if there are no items left then start again, choosing a previously unchosen item to start from.

At all times, maintain a set of visited items so that you can detect cycles.

Comment: I forgot a stipulation that multiple items might share a previous ID